# Is there a left or right preference to raising one side of the lip in contempt?

Tags: emotion

Contempt is expressed asymmetrically - one lip corner is pulled in and back, in what could be described as a half-smile.

Are there any trends in terms of people or societies which prefer pulling in one particular side over the other?

This is completely anecdotal, but ever since I originally learned about the standard emotions, I try to pay more attention to my own face, and in that time, I can't think of a single time I've ever done it with my right side - it always displays on my left.